# Scope mouse wheel to a particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following horizontal list, in which I populate many images:

```
<ul id="q" class="list-inline" style="white-space:nowrap; overflow-x:scroll; padding:5px;">
    <li v-for="index in (0,20)" :key="index" style="display:inline;" class="list-inline-item"><img :src="`${$route.params.img}`" style="width:100px; height:100px;"/></li>
</ul>
```

for this list I have created a mouse wheel listener:

```
$('#q').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta/120 > 0) {
        console.log("Up")
    }
    else{
        console.log("Down")
    }
});
```

How can I scope the mouse wheel to only this container only when the mouse pointer is over this `ul` element (preventing the actual window from going up and down due to to the mouse wheel behavior) while resuming the actual mouse wheel behavior when it leaves this particular container?

Comment: have you tried `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Also, look into http://api.jquery.com/on/ for targeting multiple elements from one element

Comment: @Isaac: Thanks, worked.

Comment: I upgraded my comment to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#q').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // <- stops the mouse wheel event from scrolling the page
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta/120 > 0) {
        console.log("Up")
    }
    else{
        console.log("Down")
    }
});
```